# Database Structure: How to define the uniqueness of a key in a table based on a 'grand-parent' table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, foreign-keys, unique-index

It's difficult to express the question title as I am lacking the terminology of what I want to achieve, so I'll write it with the precise example of what I want to do.

Having those tables:

```
Table market{
  id integer [pk]
  code varchar(32) [not null, unique]
  name varchar(32) [not null]
}

Table outcome{
  id integer [pk]
  market integer [not null, ref: > market.id]   # References market
  code varchar(32) [not null, unique]
  name varchar(32) [not null]
}

Table game{
  id integer [pk]
  match integer [not null, ref: > match.id]     # References match
  outcome integer [not null, ref: > outcome.id] # References outcome
  odd float [not null]
  status integer [not null, ref: > status.id]
  won bool [null]
}
```

How is possible to add a unique key in the table `game` ensuring that only an `outcome` per `market` per `match` ('grand-parent relationship') has a `not null` value?

Eg

```
market table
-------------------+
id | code | name   |
-------------------+
1  | vict | Victory|
1  | goal | Goals  |
-------------------+

outcome table
------------------------------------+
id | market | code | name           |
------------------------------------+
1  | 1      | home | Home           |
2  | 1      | away | Away           |
3  | 2      | one  | One            |
4  | 2      | two  | Two            |
5  | 3      | thmr | Three or More  |
------------------------------------+

game table
-------------------------------------------+
id | match | outcome | odd | status | won  |
-------------------------------------------+
1  | 1     | 1       | 1.2 | 1      | NULL |
2  | 1     | 2       | 2.5 | 1      | 1    | // OK
3  | 2     | 1       | 1.7 | 1      | 1    | 
4  | 2     | 2       | 2.4 | 1      | 1    | // ERROR
-------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it's going to be either MySQL or postgre, that's why I did not tag the question with it, as I am looking for a concept rather than a specific solution within a software. Thanks for you answer, nevertheless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases allow filtered unique indexes or something similar.

```
create unique index unq_game_market_match
    on game(market, match)
    where outcome is not null;
```

In those that do not, you can do something similar with computed columns and/or functional indexes.